# Checking for the presence of a tag in a dictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Whats the correct way to check for the absence of a tag in a dictionary.

For example :

```
self.anArray = [dict objectForKey:@"Names"];
```

Gets an item if there is one called 'Names' in the dict dictionary.

Is there a handy method to do a check to see if 'Names' exists in the dictionary.

Many Thanks,
-Code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check if `-objectForKey:` returns nil.

```
id res = [dict objectForKey:@"Names"];
if (res == nil)
   NSLog(@"Does not have Names");
else
   self.anArray = res;
```

Since an Objective-C container cannot hold nil, if `-objectForKey:` returns nil it must be the case that the corresponding key is absent.